# Why Apache POI xlsx wrap text not working?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a cell that should contain rather long text with multiple \n.
I'm using `setWrapText(true)` on a cell style object but it seems not working.
I still can only see the first line of a cell text. 
Here is the code I'm using

```
CellStyle mainHeaderCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
mainHeaderCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
mainHeaderCellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
mainHeaderCellStyle.setWrapText(true);

Cell headersCell = infoRow.createCell(cellIndex);
headersCell.setCellStyle(mainHeaderCellStyle);
headersCell.setCellValue(mainHeader);
```

But the header cell (colored in grey) is still like this
[XLSX page with header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgTNR.png)

This is the text when I double click the cell
[XLSX page with clicked header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoLL0.png)

Comment: If you put a lot of text into a single cell / row and activate `wrapText`, you might want to resize the row height as well.

Comment: In your sheet, cells `A1:K1` are merged. `Excel` is not able auto sizing the row height for merged cells. So explicit setting the row height is needed then.

Comment: Thank you @deHaar resizing row height helped!

Answer (score 2):

deHaar answer is the correct one. Resizing row height helped to fix the problem.
The working code is this

```
Row infoRow = companyDataSheet.createRow(currentRowIndex++);
CellStyle mainHeaderCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
mainHeaderCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
mainHeaderCellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
mainHeaderCellStyle.setWrapText(true);

Cell headersCell = infoRow.createCell(cellIndex);
headersCell.setCellStyle(mainHeaderCellStyle);
headersCell.setCellValue(mainHeader);
infoRow.setHeight((short) 2300);
```

Comment: Add the code that actually solved the problem, it might be helpful for future reaaders of this.